# Propulsion methods of the sentinels in the matrix

Tags: the-matrix

Whenever we see the sentinels in the matrix, they seem to be moving through pushing with their 'tentacles' like a squid, but how do they propel themselves, as they are obviously moving through air, as both sentinels and humans have been in the same environment, demanding air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of propulsion, there's no in-universe description of the method either within the film or comic canon. The [Matrix Wikia](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinel) suggests that the Sentinels are using some form of "internal pad" technology, a suggestion borne out by an examination of the concept art from George Hull, Senior Production Artist for the Matrix Trilogy;

[image: Matrix Sentinels]

As you can seen, underneath each Sentinel (and the "tow bombs" they throw) is a blue glow distinctly reminiscent of the glow seen under the Nebuchadnezzar's anti-gravity "[hoverpads](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Hoverpad)".

[image: Hoverpads]

It's also notable that whenever a Sentinel is damaged beyond its capacity to fly, they experience a bright blue internal explosion that is basically **identical** in colour and brightness to that experienced by the Hammer whenever their hoverpads are destroyed.

[image] [image]

Answer (score -2):

It's a technology called the "Pad" short for hoverpad the machines invented it and distributed it to the humans and it is used in their ships. However the machines have vastly improved it and no longer need the external "pads" seen on the ships.

Comment: What's the canon reference for this?

Comment: @DVK, truth does not need a reference - take it or leave it. `As` Switch `adequately put`: `my way or the highway`! :) (Sad, but true, btw. - reference is just a help for you to more easily see if you want to believe it or not.)

Comment: Yeah i got -3 for this.. Guy above puts pictures and gets answer

Comment: @Suavelizard I suggest you never mind, it's just a way of saying 'why should I believe you?' The answer still remains here. :) Also, you could still edit and add sources, if you wanna' do aid or just go for points.

Comment: @Suavelizard - I take exception to the suggestion that my answer was accepted because I added pictures, the reason it was accepted was because I referenced my assertions.